# nginx working with ip but not domain name

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up a django app with gunicorn and ngix. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04). Everything seems to be working but when I edit the server_name in /etc/nginx/sites-available/project to anything other than the serevr ip address I get the default nginx index page instead of the django app. When this is the server config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name <myserverip>;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/django/project;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}
```

everything works as expected (nginx serves the app) when I put the ip address into my browser, but if the I add a domain name to replace the ip or in addition to the ip all I get is the nginx page in either location. My ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py includes the server ip and the domain name. I cannot see any issue in the nginx logs either. Not sure what the issue is at this point.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to change the server_name to include your domain:

```
server_name <myserverip> <mydomainname>;
```

Feel free to drop the ip address if you only want to be able to access the site using your domain name. You'll also want to add any subdomains (i.e. www) you want to serve the same site. For example:

```
server_name youdomainname.com www.yourdomainname.com;
```

Don't forget to restart nginx after updating the config file.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue. The nginx default configuration /etc/nginx/sites-available/default was shadowing mine. I commented out the server portion of the default configuration and the domain is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In server_name you can write an IP or URL, but at the same time in your settings.py you must give it permission.

[settings.py]

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP', 'URL']
```

Here, I uploaded something to my github that can help you:

[Github/Nginx](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/nginx.md)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue was that it was working with the ip but not the domain even though both were in settings.py and the nginx config.

Comment: In that case you can add logs to your Nginx or Gunicorn, to test the fault, and also debug True in Django.

At the same time you can use systemctl status Gunicorn/Nginx, to see if everything is going well.